# Listing ordering Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have made a new content type. Consequently i made a list of it, and created a new widget so to display that list.

The problem is that even by changing the order in the widget properties, the list is ordered by the oldest date descending.

I want to have the newer entries up top, but can't work around it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Queries for generating the list?

Comment: @Dairo care to explain a bit more? I just create a new instance of the contant type and it automatically gets updated in both page/widget section.

Comment: On the menu on the left, below Content Definition is a button called Queries.By clicking on it you can create a new Query. You can add a sort criteria on the query  like descending the publication date

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxid4XYStMc

Comment: @Dairo Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that option, stili i can't find anything to do with sort rather than filtering. Anyway thanks again, will find it out eventually. EDIT: Blindness, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To put the newest of your new content type at the top:

1. Create a Query.
2. In your new Query, add a new Filter selecting for "Content -> Content types". Find your new content type in the dropdown.
3. Also add a new Sort Criterion that looks at "Common Part Record -> Publication date" and then choose either ascending or descending.
4. On the Widget page, add a new Projection Widget to the section you want. Set up your widget and choose the Query you just made.

Hope that helps!